# Matplotlib shows blank window

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

The code runs fine on Linux but when I try it on MacOS Ventura the popup Python window shows blank figure. It is a matplotlib plot, but pretty heavy. Do you have any ideas on resolving it for MacOS?

Comment: It will help us to answer your question if you could share what trouble shooting steps you have followed to solve the issue - particularly, information about python and matplotlib version.

Comment: can you include a minimum reproducible example? ideally the minimum amount of code that we can run ourselves in order to reproduce your error